# Azure Service Bus Topic: EntityAvailabilityStatus.Limited

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

What does it mean if [EntityAvailabilityStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.entityavailabilitystatus?view=azure-dotnet) is set to Limited? Is it possible to write to or read from a topic in this state?

We have an availability monitor function that tests a service bus topic availability by inspecting the property above. Every day or two, monitor fails for a few minutes with EntityAvailabilityStatus == Limited instead of Available:

```
var topic = namespaceManager.GetTopic(settings.ServiceBusTopicName);
if (topic.AvailabilityStatus != EntityAvailabilityStatus.Available)
{
//fail
}
```

Comment: My guess would be the entity can receive, but undergoes some server side changes. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.entityavailabilitystatus) is super criptic. I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/150) for this enumeration. Hopefully ASB team would clarify what that value stands for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using partitioned topics this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning) may help.

Specifically

> Management: Operations such as Create, Update and Delete must be performed on all the fragments of the entity. If any fragment is unhealthy, it could result in failures for these operations. For the Get operation, information such as message counts must be aggregated from all fragments. If any fragment is unhealthy, the entity availability status is reported as limited.